# Unity with ARKit- splash screen displays for REALLY long time?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, load-time

Ok, I am working with the below version of Unity and have integrated the ARKit plugin, just building a basic app. I don't believe Ive used a ton of objects/anyting crazy to load.

[image]

Issue is my splash screen time is REALLY long (up to 30+ seconds) on the dark blue just before the Unity logo. My build settings:

[image]

What could cause this? What can I do to make splash screen/app load time more normal?

Comment: The short answer: get Pro, and disable the splash screen. The long version: run a profiler and see where the execution time is going (I'm guessing resource loading or waiting on a network connection), and optimize that part.

Comment: You have `Development build` on with `Script Debugging`. That could be one of the reasons.

Comment: @Hristo hm.. what is the best build settings for fast load time/splash screen/performance? Why is script debugging slower?

Comment: The `Development build/Script Debugging` Would increase the total size of your app and will reduce the performance by a little. Those flags are used whenever you want to test your code on the actual build. So you could debug the actual device, instead of the `Unity Editor`. It will also have a more detailed output in terms of `Logging`. You should not unable if the application is going to be a release.